# Duvida com a ide Dbeaver

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, dbeaver

Estou utilizando o *DBeaver* com o SGBD *oracle*.

Queria fazer uma média de tempo de execução para comparar na hora das otimizações, porém estou em duvida, o que significa

> ```
> "688 row(s) fetched - 3ms (+20ms)"
> ```

com esse 3ms fora dos parênteses e o 20 dentro e formas de otimizar consultas, pois ainda sou novo nisso.

[image: Queria dicas de como usar também]

Answer (score 2):

Essa função foi implementada como uma solução para a issue #1478:

https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/1478

Segundo o código-fonte, a parte fora dos parênteses é o **execution time** e a de dentro é o **fetch time**. O **execution time** é o tempo que o banco de dados leva para identificar os registros que devem ser retornados com base na sua consulta. O **fetch time** é quanto o banco demorou para entregar os dados.

Logo, se você fizer SELECT * FROM ANO_MODELO o banco não terá quase nenhum trabalho para identificar os registros que devem ser retornados, uma vez que você quer a tabela toda. Então, você teria um menor **execution time** porém um maior **fetch time**, pois a quantidade de registros é maior e requer mais tempo para ser buscada.

Abaixo está o trecho de código que detalha a implementação (fonte GitHub):

```
    if (statistics == null || statistics.isEmpty()) {
        return "";
    }

    long fetchTime = statistics.getFetchTime();
    long totalTime = statistics.getTotalTime();
    if (fetchTime <= 0) {
        return " - " + RuntimeUtils.formatExecutionTime(totalTime);
    } else {
        return " - " + RuntimeUtils.formatExecutionTime(statistics.getExecuteTime()) + " (+" + RuntimeUtils.formatExecutionTime(fetchTime) + ")";
    }
}
```